# Выбор команды в зависимости от состояния формы

Tags: wpf, xaml

Можно ли на один элемент в xaml повесить несколько команда и в зависимости от какой-нибудь галочки на форме выполнять ту или иную команду? Или нужно бредить конкретную команду, а уже внутри делать выбор?

Comment: Есть еще вариант, когда делается несколько элементов с привязками к разным командам и регулируется их видимость.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353611/wpf-button-command-binding-after-trigger-the-propery-changes